# Create an Image Target from a Device Database at Runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

Using the follow code:
https://library.vuforia.com/unity-extension/create-and-load-targets-unity#create-an-image-target-from-a-device-database-at-runtime

This action never pops:
 `mImageTarget.OnTargetStatusChanged += OnTargetStatusChanged;`

There is no way to know if an image target is tracked or not.

Tried adding an observer manually, does not appear in runtime hierarchy, doesn't pop any actions (which it should, as described)

mImageTarget.gameObject.AddComponent();

I want to simply change the image target at runtime and check if the image is tracked or not..

Has anyone had similar experience and found a way around this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the target actually loaded correctly and that it is actually trackable? Does the same target work in the Vuforia sample? Have you checked the log for errors?